# Check if `_GNU_SOURCE` or `_BSD_SOURCE` is supported by the libc?

Tags: c, cmake, glibc, libc, asprintf

I am curious if `asprintf` is available. Some libc implementations provide it under specific *Feature Test Macros*. Namely if you `#define _GNU_SOURCE` or `#define _BSD_SOURCE` you can get `asprintf` and a few other nice nonstandard extensions when you `#include <stdio.h>`.

There are a decent number of libc implementation. glibc obviously has `asprintf`; but so do a number of others.

How do I test if the libc implementation supports `_BSD_SOURCE` or `_GNU_SOURCE`?

My current test is bad, as it's just a kernel check not a compiler + libc + version check:

```c
#if defined(__linux) || defined(__linux__) || defined(linux)
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#elif defined(BSD) || defined(__FreeBSD__) || defined(__FreeBSD__) ||          \
    defined(__NetBSD__) || defined(__OpenBSD__) || defined(__bsdi__) ||        \
    defined(__DragonFly__)
#define _BSD_SOURCE
#endif
#include <stdio.h>
```

PS: I'm also using CMake and considered a `check_symbol_exists(asprintf "stdio.h" HAVE_ASPRINTF)` but not sure that'd suffice.

Comment: You don't need to check for the macros. Use `check_symbol_exists` to check for the function and optionally (cuz e.g., `gcc` has `_GNU_SOURCE` pre-defined) provide `CMAKE_REQUIRED_DEFINITIONS` (e.g., in a `foreach` loop try w/o macro, and then add one repeating the check)

Comment: Since these macros have no effect on systems that don't support them, why not simply define all of them, unconditionally?

Comment: @zwol Because that won't tell me if `asprintf` is available.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of a fully working example, we'll start with:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(example)
```

It probably doesn't need 3.25, but that's what I tested it on, so YMMV.

Now, here's a fairly robust function you can use to try several different preprocessor definitions in service of ensuring a target can see a symbol:

```
include(CheckSymbolExists)

function(ensure_symbol)
  cmake_parse_arguments(PARSE_ARGV 0 ARG "PUBLIC" "TARGET;SYMBOL" "INCLUDES;DEFINITIONS")

  # Determine visibility for symbols that need to be added
  get_property(type TARGET "${ARG_TARGET}" PROPERTY TYPE)
  if (type STREQUAL "INTERFACE_LIBRARY")
    set(visibility INTERFACE)
  elseif (ARG_PUBLIC)
    set(visibility PUBLIC)
  else ()
    set(visibility PRIVATE)
  endif ()

  # The base name of the cache variables to create
  string(TOUPPER "HAVE_${ARG_SYMBOL}" var_name)

  # Check the base version
  check_symbol_exists("${ARG_SYMBOL}" "${ARG_INCLUDES}" "${var_name}")

  if (${var_name})
    return ()
  endif ()

  # Otherwise, start trying alternatives
  foreach (def IN LISTS ARG_DEFINITIONS)
    set(local_name "${var_name}${def}")

    set(CMAKE_REQUIRED_DEFINITIONS "-D${def}")
    check_symbol_exists("${ARG_SYMBOL}" "${ARG_INCLUDES}" "${local_name}")

    if (${local_name})
      target_compile_definitions("${ARG_TARGET}" "${visibility}" "${def}")
      return()
    endif ()
  endforeach ()

  message(FATAL_ERROR "Could not ensure ${ARG_TARGET} can use ${ARG_SYMBOL}")
endfunction()
```

It uses `check_symbol_exists` in a loop over candidate symbols to define in order to make the symbol available. Whichever one works, it attaches to the target via `target_compile_definitions`.

The main complicating feature is that it gives users control over the visibility of the definition to linkees. It's always `INTERFACE` for interface libraries (which is required), but for other target types, it defaults to `PRIVATE`. The user may set it to `PUBLIC` by passing the appropriate option to `ensure_symbol`.

Finally, using it is pretty simple:

```
add_executable(myapp main.cpp)
ensure_symbol(
  TARGET myapp
  SYMBOL asprintf
  INCLUDES stdio.h
  DEFINITIONS _GNU_SOURCE _BSD_SOURCE
)
```

---

I tested it locally, and it adds `_GNU_SOURCE` on my machine, which can be seen at the bottom of the following output:

```
$ cmake -G Ninja -S . -B build -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.3.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Looking for asprintf
-- Looking for asprintf - not found
-- Looking for asprintf
-- Looking for asprintf - found
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/alex/test/build
$ cmake --build build/ --verbose
[1/2] /usr/bin/c++ -D_GNU_SOURCE  -O3 -DNDEBUG -MD -MT CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/main.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/main.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/main.cpp.o -c /home/alex/test/main.cpp
[2/2] : && /usr/bin/c++ -O3 -DNDEBUG  CMakeFiles/myapp.dir/main.cpp.o -o myapp   && :
```